# Acessing $_SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart

I'm creating an Inventory system in PHP

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM booklists WHERE book_id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $product_name = $row["book_name"];
```

When I echo my `$_SESSION` using this

```
 print_r($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
```

I added 2 item in the cart with the quantity of 1 and 55

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 37 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 32 [quantity] => 55 ) 
)
```

I wanna update all of the `[quantity]` values in my session. how do you think I can achieve it ?

Comment: $_SESSION is an array, like any other. The **ONLY** thing that makes it special is that it gets auto-loaded/auto-saved via the session mechanism. Other than that, you access/update/delete things in it like any OTHER array.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't overly clear, as I don't know what the quantity needs updating by, but to update each `quantity`, you could do something like this.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => $item){
    // Add 1 to each quantity
    $_SESSION['cart_array'][$index]['quantity']++;
}

// Or...

$increaseBy = 5;
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => $item){
    // Increase by a fixed amount.
    $_SESSION['cart_array'][$index]['quantity'] += $increaseBy;
}

// Or...

foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => $item){
    // Increase by a random number between 5 and 15.
    $_SESSION['cart_array'][$index]['quantity'] += rand(5, 15);
}

// Or...

foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => $item){
    $increaseBy = $this->getQuantityIncrease($item['item_id']);
    $_SESSION['cart_array'][$index]['quantity'] += $increaseBy;
}

// Or...
// By using references.
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => &$item){
    $increaseBy = $this->getQuantityIncrease($item['item_id']);
    $item['quantity'] += $increaseBy;
}
```

Comment: Sir I just noticed, Why still use `$_SESSION['cart_array'][$index]['quantity']++` if you are already in foreach? I think you can use just `$item['quantity']++`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That would only update the local variable `$item`, it wouldn't actually update the $_SESSION array. I believe if you change the foreach to use `&$item` that may fix that, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: @rmondesilva I was correct, see this example https://ideone.com/iQ9t5m . Without using `&`, making it a reference, it won't update in the array. I've added an example using a reference.

Comment: I see. Thank you Sir for letting me to know that. Additional knowledge for me.

Comment: @rmondesilva No problem :). Don't forget, if this answered your question you can mark it by clicking the tick mark under the votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your loop,

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $key => $item) { 
  $_SESSION['cart_array'][$key]['quantity'] = 13; // set the qty you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop to do this.

```
$newQuantityValue = 10;

foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $key => $value){
    $_SESSION[$key]['quantity'] = $newQuantityValue;
}
```

All we do here is assign a new value for our quantity and then use a foreach loop to iterate through the `$_SESSION` variable so that we can update each of your quantity fields with our new value (in this case 10).

For more information about foreach loops, check out the [the PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

---

**Pass By Reference:**

You could equally change the value by passing it by reference like this:

```
$newQuantityValue = 10;

foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $key => &$value){
    $value['quantity'] = $newQuantityValue;
}
```

Because we are passing it by reference, there is no longer any need to reference the `$_SESSION`

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

---

*As a side note*:
You could dispense with the `$newQuantityValue` variable all together and instead just put the number into the loop like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $key => $value){
    $_SESSION[$key]['quantity'] = 10;
}
```